# Use font-awesome in a Vue app created with vue-cli webpack

Tags: webpack, font-awesome, vuejs2

I'm trying to use the font-awesome in a simple Vue app created with vue-cli using the webpack-simple template, but this is being tricky.

I installed font-awesome using `npm install font-awesome --save` and imported it in my entry js (main.js)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Home from "./components/Home.vue"

Vue.use(VueRouter);

import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Home }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'history'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

This is my current webpack.config.js file:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
            // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
            // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this nessessary.
            'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
            'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/, 
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
      }, {
        test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
      }, {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream"
      }, {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "file"
      }, {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml"
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

I already tried change the font loaders to the following:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpe|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?.*$|$)/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
    }
}
```

But both configurations throws the same error:

```
ERROR in ./~/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
Module parse failed: /home/james/projects/app/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css Unexpected character '@' (7:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| /* FONT PATH
|  * -------------------------- */
| @font-face {
|   font-family: 'FontAwesome';
|   src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
 @ ./src/main.js 11:0-43
 @ multi main
```

After some google, I found some links ([here](https://github.com/gowravshekar/font-awesome-webpack), [here](https://gist.github.com/Turbo87/e8e941e68308d3b40ef6) and [here](https://github.com/webpack/less-loader/issues/53) for example), but any of them work for me, the error is always the same.

Whats is the recommended loader to deal with font-awesome files? I think the problem is in the loader, because all regex expressions looks fine to me.

For information, below is the versions in `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bulma": "^0.3.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "vue": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-router": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "vue-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.25",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.1.0-beta.9"
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you need to include a loader for `.css` in your webpack configuration:

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'css-loader'
  },
```

Comment: Maybe "css-loader" only is not enough. You can try `loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'` or `loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?sourceMap'` (with source maps).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it right now, but its not work. I intaled `npm install css-loader --save-dev` and include your suggest config, but now I receiving the error 
`/home/james/Projects/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:35
   throw new Error("Module '" + loader.path + "' is not a loader (must have normal or pitch function)");
   ^

Error: Module '/home/james/Projects/app/node_modules/url/url.js' is not a loader (must have normal or pitch function)`. Any tip?

Comment: In your `loader:` configs, instead of `url`, use `url-loader`. (For example, change `loader: "url?limit=10000` to `loader: "url-loader?limit=10000`. You also have a `loader: 'file'` which should be `loader: 'file-loader'`. According to your `package.json`, you have all loaders installed. No need to install anything else. Final tip: use Webpack 1 while Webpack 2 is still beta (unless you already know enough of Webpack 1 or you have a good and strong reason for using Webpack 2).

Comment: The warnings and errors are gone now, but my icons still does not appear in the page :/. I'm marking your response as correct, since it solved the initial problem, but please enter your comments in the answer to help others. I'll keep trying to use font-awesome in my project.

Comment: Side note: The vue-cli template "webpack-simple" already starts the project using webpack 2. I'll try to change it for version 1.

Answer (score 18):

With the **FontAwesome-5** release some exclusive things are done by FontAwesome team for vue and other libraries:

Kinda **outdated solution** but still works, check the updated solution below:

- Check fontawesome advance options [here](https://fontawesome.com/get-started/advanced-options)
- For npm package and doc check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome)

Anyhow, here is what I did to integrate it, first
installed these packages:

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome
npm i --save @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid
```

Create a file called `fa.config.js` and included this code:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome';
import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import {
  faSpinner,
  faAngleLeft,
  faAngleRight,
} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid';

fontawesome.library.add(
  faSpinner,
  faAngleLeft,
  faAngleRight,
);

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon); // registered globally
```

And import it in `main.js`

```
import './path/to/fa.config';
```

And in my components I am using it like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <font-awesome-icon icon="angle-left"></font-awesome-icon> Hey! FA Works
  </div>
</template>
```

By now you guys might have figured it out what's the advantage of doing as I have done it above?

> Using an explicit icon offers the advantage of only bundling the icons
>   that you use in your final bundled file. This allows us to subset Font
>   Awesome's thousands of icons to just the small number that are
>   normally used.

Hope this helps!

---

**UPDATE - Friday, 22 June 2018**
The above solution still works but now things are done in different way, first install these packages:

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons // if "regular" icon package needed
npm i --save @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome
```

Then create a file called `fa.config.js` and included this code:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

import { faUser, faBuilding } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faUserCircle, faCheckCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'

library.add(
  faUser,
  faBuilding,
  faUserCircle,
  faCheckCircle,
);

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon); // registered globally
```

Say that you like you use `faUser` icon of both the kind `regular` and `solid`, then do this change:

```
import { faUser as fasUser, faBuilding } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faUser as farUser, faCheckCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'

library.add(
  fasUser,
  farUser,
  faBuilding,
  faCheckCircle,
);
```

And import it in main.js

```
import './path/to/fa.config';
```

And in my components I am using it like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <font-awesome-icon icon="user"></font-awesome-icon>

    // If you like to use Font Awesome Regular, then:
    <font-awesome-icon :icon="['far', 'user']"></font-awesome-icon>
    <font-awesome-icon :icon="['far', 'check-circle']"></font-awesome-icon>

  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I import and render common icon type like arrow-up etc? I don't see it exported in free-solid-svg-icons.

Comment: @Raja there is nothing like common or uncommon every thing has to be imported manually as I have done it above, like in your case `import { faArrowUp, faUser, faBuilding } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'` and then add to library like this: `library.add(faUser, faArrowUp)` and you can use it like this: `<font-awesome-icon icon="arrow-up"></font-awesome-icon>`

Answer (score 0):

I use simple solution webpack:

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve('resources/js')
        }
    }
}
```

webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'))

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version()
}
```

use sass, in app.scss

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss';
```

install all dependency
i use in package.json:

```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
"@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
```

don't break your main and invok it

```
<i class="fa fa-icon> </i>
<i class="fas fa-icon> </i> // for solid
<i class="far fa-icon> </i> // for Regular
```

and imaginated how is brands.!

Answer (score 0):

**for fa and fab icons**

use npm :

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome
```

in Main.js :

```
// font awesome 5 
import fontawesome from "@fortawesome/fontawesome";
import solid from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid";
import brands from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands";

fontawesome.library.add( brands , solid);
```

and call icons as you normally would on website development

in home.vue :

```
<a href="#!" class="text-white me-4">
    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f" />
 </a>
```